# Transactional Email Formatting

Tags: magento-1.7, css

When I upgraded a store from 1.3.2.4 → 1.7.0.2, suddenly the transactional emails (order confirmations) have slightly different formatting, even though none of those settings changed.

See the example below:

**Old transactional email**

P.S. I removed the item names & SKUs deliberately.

[image: Old transactional email format]

*Note the line item color coding & light blue headers / grand total rows & text formatting of Grand Total*

**New transactional email**

[image: New transactional email format]

*Note how the previously light blue column header row is now grey, Grand Total row is no longer light blue or formatted*

**Where can I begin to look into this?**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the mail templates under `System - Transactional E-Mails`. Probably the new default ones of Magento 1.7 are used now. And they indeed changed the colour. Just compare the appropriate template of [Magento 1.3](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.3/app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html) and [Magento 1.7](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html) with a tool like [QuickDiff](http://www.quickdiff.com/). It will show you all the changes. And the colour of the table headings have indeed been changed from `#d9e5ee` to `#EAEAEA`. Of course you can edit the colour in the admin under `System - Transactional E-Mails` again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Making those changes doesn't seem to change it back unfortunately. I'm starting to believe it may have something to do with https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml but am still looking into it, cause it seems that file doesn't exist in 1.3

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right templates? Have a look under `System - Configuration - Sales - Sales Emails` of the correct scope (!) and see which mail templates are actually used. AFAIK only the content present in the template will be sent, nothing else.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the HTML of the mail which is actually sent and look where the CSS definitions exactly come from.

Comment: The only reference I see in the `order_new.html` file is `{{var items_html}}`. I'm trying to establish where that is defined, will report back as soon as I find more info. Appreciate your input very much.